# Proper way to say you haven't met someone

Tags: expressions

What options are there to politely say you haven't met someone yet? For example if you have a common acquaintance online who asks if you know each other.

"I haven't had the pleasure to meet him yet"

or

"I haven't had the opportunity to meet him yet"

Are there better expressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One small modification will make your expressions correct, polite ways to express it:

> I haven't had the pleasure/opportunity **of meeting** him yet.

Shorthand for either (especially the first) expression is fine, also:

> I haven't had the pleasure.

Comment: In my experience, “I haven’t had the pleasure” doesn’t mean quite this: that would more typically be said directly *to* the person you don’t know, with the meaning “we haven’t been introduced” (cf. [“I don’t believe I’ve had the pleasure”](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/don%27t+believe+I%27ve+had+the+pleasure).

Comment: Or simply "we have not yet met".

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's anything impolite in simply saying, "No, we've not yet met" or "No, we haven't met".

Perhaps I'm ruder than some, but I've never sincerely used the expression "I haven't had the pleasure".

Comment: Agreed, although I still use formal conventions in formal situations.  But no one can be sincere in expressing fondness for an unknown person.  Form letters signed "Best regards" or any automated politeness strike me as hollow and in fact detract from genuine human sincerity.  I hope this sort of thing is a passing fad.

Comment: I often hear/read the expression "I haven't had the pleasure" used in an obviously ironic sense, i.e. the person concened is clearly not a pleasure to meet. I'd be careful with the context/tone when using it.

Answer (score 0):

I never had the pleasure of meeting her

Comment: Please explain why your answer is correct; answers without explanation don't teach the patterns of English well and may be deleted.

Answer (score -2):

I've YET to have the pleasure/opportunity. Just bring the preposition forward.

Comment: Which preposition would that be?